# Частое обращение к серверу

Tags: ajax, php, mysql

Всем привет. Задумался о проблеме с нагрузкой на сервер. Думаю, нужно сделать ограничение на частоту запросов, в частности с ajax. 
Ограничить пользователя на 15 сек, если частота одного обращения ниже 5 секунд.
Не могу представить, какие методы варианта могут быть. Думал, что можно брать последнюю запись из базы и смотреть на время добавления, но это не функциональный метод, да и к тому же не выгодный, так как запрос к базе в любом случае нужно делать.

Какие варианты решения такой задачи есть? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это или делать средствами nginx/Apache/iptables или вообще не делать. 
Т.к. у вас цель снизить нагрузку на сервер от слишком "активных" пользователей. Можно сказать от DDOS. Как раз одна из защит от DDOS это запрет с 1 IP на много запросов.

Answer (score 0):

Счетчик запросов, обнуляемый через `CountDownTimer` каждые N минут в клиентской JavaScript части, которая посылает AJAX запрос, может помочь. Правда это не спасет вас от того, что пользователь может обновить страницу через CTRL+F5, тогда таймер пойдет заново или кто-то станет обращаться к вашему серверу не из браузера. В таком случае нужно конфигурировать HTTP сервер.

Comment: Со стороны сервера (PHP) возможна реализация?

Comment: Можно попробовать, чтобы счетчик числа обращений передавался в PHP скрипт как GET параметр и сервер сам бы решал, что делать, если параметр больше определенного числа, при этом на клиентской стороне сохранять его как cookie и при этом загружать это cookie каждый раз, когда пользователь обновляет страницу. Как-то так.

Comment: Не безопасно. =(